# odoo-How to save related fields for one2many relation

Tags: odoo

my problem is that when i saved the fields in model's from B , i did't saw the result in model's view A execept the name of empoyee and department becuse declared in the same model, some freinds suggeste me to use onchnage function but how !!

```
class FeuilleTemps(models.Model):  # A
    _name = 'tbrh.feuilletemps'
    _rec_name = 'name_emp'

    name_emp = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employé")
    name_dep = fields.Many2one('hr.department', string="Département")
    abscence_ids = fields.One2many('tbrh.abscences', 'feuille_id', string="ma liste ")

    relation_id = fields.Many2one('tbrh.abscences')
    date2 = fields.Date(related='relation_id.date', store=True, use_parent_address=False)
    statut = fields.Selection(related='relation_id.statut', store=True)



class Abscences(models.Model):  # B
    _name = 'tbrh.abscences'

    statut = fields.Selection([('abscent', 'Abscent'), ('present', 'Présent')], string="Statut")
    date = fields.Date()
    feuille_id = fields.Many2one('tbrh.feuilletemps',
                                 ondelete='cascade', string="feuille ", required=True)
```

Comment: The related fields `date2` and `statut` has nothing to do with the One2many fields, The two fields will be filled only if `relation_id` field is or the field specified in `related` is set.

Comment: thank you but this is not my problem,  How can i show fields in view A froù other model B in this cas

Comment: Since `abscence_ids ` lists records from `B`, you have just to use an One2many list to show `abscence_ids `, <field name="abscence_ids" widget="one2many_list">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="date"/>
                                <field name="statut"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>. Sorry for the formatting

Comment: he works perfectly thnak you so so much for the all

Comment: You are welcome.